# Why was Talking Tina invincible?

Tags: the-twilight-zone

In 1963, Rod Serling released a Twilight Zone episode (Living Doll) that featuring an evil doll known as "Talking Tina," who could not be harmed in any way.

**Why couldn't Talking Tina be hurt?**

Comment: http://twilightzone.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Doll

Comment: Because it is the Twilight Zone.... No reason was given in the episode.

Comment: @WayneInYak - I'm trying to find a cast/crew interview with the word "magic" or "cursed" in it.

Comment: I think a talking doll that says I'm going to kill you pretty much says this isn't normal

Answer (score 12):

As much as I hate to say it, "Because magic".

When Erich tries to crush Talky-Tina, he can't crush her. When he tries to burn her, the flame goes out without any apparent reason for doing so and when he tries to cut her, the blade sparks but leaves no visible scarring on the doll's neck.

None of these are *explicable*, which only leaves the *inexplicable*.

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced plot-hole-ogy is indistinguishable from magic